# foreach returned undefined in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/m8m2I9dqE2kF1H1nzxJT?p=preview

```
  $scope.links = [
    {'link':'www.google.com'},
        {'link':'www.ask.com'},
            {'link':'www.yahoo.com'}


    ];

      $scope.openLinks = function(){
        var urls = '';
        angular.forEach($scope.links, function(){
            $window.open("link.html/?" + $scope.links.link);
    });

  };
```

I want to loop through an array and open each of them in the new windows but I got undefined.

Comment: Am I missing something in Angular? Shouldn't that be `$scope.links.forEach(function(el){ /* you want to access el.link for the URL */ });`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the angular documentation, [forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) works something like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.links, function(link, key) {
    $window.open("link.html/?" + link);
});
```

Comment: Ah, so [I *was* missing something in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356043/foreach-returned-undefined-in-my-case#comment37659781_24356043)...

Comment: what if multiple links blocked by popup, any idea bout this?

Comment: What do you mean, they are blocked by a popup? The site you opened, opened a popup as well?

Answer (score 2):

This should fix it:

```
angular.forEach($scope.links, function(item){
        $window.open("link.html/?" + item.link);
});
```